# Having trouble pushing dynamic key-value pairs to the data layer using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to collect and fire form fields as dataLayer variables using Google Tag Manager:

```
<script>
  
  var fields = [];
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll("input");  
  
  var x = fields.forEach(function(field) {
    var obj = {};
    var a = field.getAttribute("name");
    var b = field.value;
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      obj[a] = b
    });
  }); 
  
</script>
```

My intention is, when triggered, to:

1. Collect all of the form values in fields
2. Iterate over the array of items and get the field's name and value
3. Fire the name and value as a key-value pair
4. Return to iterate over the next item.

However, I'm receiving the error:

> Error at line 12, character 10: Parse error. '}' expected

And no matter what changes I make, I can't seem to properly trouble shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `=` in the `push` function. You can change your code slightly.
Do the assignment before pushing like `obj[a] = b`, and then push the object in dataLayer at each iteration.

---

Working code logic below

```js
var fields = [];
var fields = document.querySelectorAll("input");

var x = fields.forEach(function(field) {
  var obj = {};
  var a = field.getAttribute("name");
  var b = field.value;
  obj[a] = b;
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push(obj);
});

console.log(dataLayer)
```

```html
<input name='a' value='a' />
<input name='b' value='b' />
<input name='c' value='c' />
```

Comment: Tushar - you are a golden god, thank you for your help. 1,000 blessings upon you.

Comment: Can you  please accept the answer mate and upvote if possible?